# Modal HTML 5 video mute on close?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a video that plays in a modal How ever when ever you close it the sound continues to play in the background.  I want to know if there is a way to pause the video when the modal closes? I am using Materialize library.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.96.1/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.96.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="card-panel">
  <div class="row center">
    <h1>Welcome to project Husky!</h1>
    <h5><span class="element"></span></h5>
    <a class="modal-trigger waves-effect waves-light btn" href="#modal3">Modal</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal Structure -->

  <div id="modal3" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="row center">
        <video width="900" controls>
          <source src="videos/husky.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
              Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
        </video>
           <script>

    $('#modal3').closeModal();
   function pauseVid() {
       vid.pause();
   }
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat ">Agree</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

MCEV:

```
     <script>

    $('#modal3').closeModal();
    $('videos/husky.mp4').get(0).pause();
        </script>
```

Comment: Are you sure `hidden.bs.modal` event handler is called?

Comment: @A.Wolff I am not sure actually what the event hadler is called in http://materializecss.com/modals.html

Comment: I was just about to ask exactly the same!

Comment: But seems easy to check it at least... Set a `console.log(666)` and check

Comment: @A.Wolff No results where found from console.

Comment: But isn't it a custom bootstrap twitter event? Are you including it?

Comment: @A.Wolff  I think it is I am using materialize sorry I did not specify the modals can be found here: http://materializecss.com/modals.html

Comment: Well i don't see anything in doc you just provided regarding any `hidden.bs.modal` event. That's a custom bootstrap event, nothing to do with what you are using (if i'm correct). Have you just read the link you provided, they said how to bind close event  `complete: function() { alert('Closed'); } // Callback for Modal close`

Comment: @A.Wolff I tried it now still did not work!

Comment: @ed_laika Sorry but cannot help you more, still not sure what you tried or not. Can you just provide a MCVE replicating your issue?

Comment: I would avoid that materialize plugin. All the evidence suggests it to be unreliable, and the documentation is poor. Try jQueyUI's modal instead.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Here: <script>

        $('#modal3').closeModal();
       function pauseVid() {
           vid.pause();
       }
            </script>

Comment: @ed_laika your edited code as no meaning. Again provide MCVE if you want someone else to be able to fix it... In doc they said to use `complete` option so what about it???

Comment: Sorry but i give up. Just looks like you have no idea what you are doing. And read more carefully materialize doc, all is explained

Comment: @A.Wolff I fixed it thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pause()` method does not exist on the jQuery object; it's on the underlying DOM element, so you need to use either of the below methods to pause the video:

```
$('video')[0].pause();
```

or

```
$('video').get(0).pause();
```

Comment: jQuery would call the native DOM method AFAIK